# phpmyadmin index.php file disappeared

Tags: linux, security, phpmyadmin, debian

I am having a very strange problem.
I am having a Debian machinem, 
once in a while the `index.php` file of my phpMyAdmin disappearing, and I need to reinstall / copy it back.
I don't know what causes this weird behavior.
and I thought that maybe someone had hacked to my machine, so I had tightened my iptables rules. and set the permission on the `index.php` file to read only for user,group,and everyone.

And still it been deleted today.
I don't know what to do, I had googled to see if this might happend because of bug of any kind, or software update. but couldn't find any hints.

So here is my question:
**1**. does anyone encountered such behavior?
**2**. if someone hacked into my server how can I find it? (there is no unknown login in my  logs, and I had checked all the IP's of the logins seems to be a valid known my IP's)
**3**. how can I find out what is deleting or causing this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Debian does update apt with security fixes as a cron-job if not turned off. This may move files to "default" positions.

Answer (score 0):

it seems my machine was hacked, so I had just created a new machine with tighter security and this never occurred again up to now.